# Conflicting iis rewrite rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have the following redirects in my web.config?

```
<rule name="module1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^module1\/?" ignoreCase="true" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.somesite.com" />
</rule>

<rule name="module10" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^module10\/?" ignoreCase="true"/>
     <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.someothersite.com" />
</rule>
```

When I type in www.mysite.com/module10, I'm getting the redirect to module1.

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A user in the IIS forum gave me the answer.  If I put the module10 redirect ahead of the module1 redirect in the web.config, then everything will work fine.